# IoT Hub - modify complex token creation (via MQTT)

Tags: azure, mqtt, sha256, hmac, azure-iot-hub

as per my heading I would really like to look into doing this, let me explain why.

History : I have successfully done a full host and client and its working 100% on via .NET. The big but is that our clients in the field are running on a microcontroller (not a microprocessor) that has poor encryption libraries (embedded C, in particular PIC). Our firmware engineer guy is currently battling to get the HMAC part of the SAS token generation to work. The other pieces of the hub is possible (MQTT, TLS, URL encoding, EPOCH etc) but the HMAC SHA256 is a struggle.

I am aware of the protocol gateway offered where you can replace the gateway’s authentication provider. Does anyone have any sample code/guide that I can follow. The dev guide offered by Microsoft seems limited or maybe im just being silly and missing the plot.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light bulb moment ;) So we going to keep our TCP channel open and will get the unit to help auth over this channel. I will ACK back the key (will encrypt that in a much simpler way ;))